# How can I store the Claims by Azure Authentication in Session in .net Core?

Tags: .net, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

MY application - .Net Core MVC 3.1 is using Microsoft.Identity.Web and Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI for Microsoft Authentication and I receive claims. I have policy based authorization which on every hit to controller checks the users roles from DB and provides the permission to land. But I want to achieve following cases-

1> If I can redirect user from Microsoft Authentication page to a particular Controller for once where i can read the claims and add extra claims and can store it into session which can be used throughout the application and can save the unnecessary db hit on every authorization.
But after authentication currently my application is redirecting to the url which user was trying to access i.e. redirectUrl.

2> If above step is not possible, Can we store the claims after AUthentication using custom middleware into some session which can be access by anywhere.
But problem is that custom middleware will be called everytime and everytime it will check db to store the session. Secondly, HTTPConetext Session is getting cleared on every new request. How can I have session of my own which should not get cleared?

Comment: If you are using Asp.net Identity with Azure Authentication, you could check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and the [claims-based identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/claims), after login successfully, you could use the UserManager AddClaimAsync method to add the specified claim to the user, after the authentication flow is complete, the claims are available in HttpContext.User.

Comment: Otherwise, you could check the following articles to use session in asp.net core:[Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [Custom Authorization in Asp.net Core](https://forums.asp.net/t/2139529.aspx?Custom+Authorization+in+Asp+net+Core)

Comment: Hi @ZhiLv, Thanks for the reply. But I am not using Microsoft Identity framework for users and roles. Also, I am adding the claims to HttpContext.User.Identity but these claims are not getting saved for every request. And on every request, i need to read the claims provided by azure and need to fetch the user roles and permissions and again need to add into claims list for that request. Need to do this for every request.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore using ASP .NET core Distributed Cache here: https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-core-session-storage-strategies